# How can I log a REST request with Jersey without actually sending the request?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

I am using Jersey-client-2.28 library to make REST requests. 
I have found code on the web that facilitates logging and it works fine.

The problem I have is I do not want to actually send the request. In other words, I do not want to put the data on wire. All I want is to prepare the request object and then print it.

Is this possible with Jersey?

```
Feature feature = new LoggingFeature(logger, Level.INFO, null, null);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(feature).build();

URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUrl).build();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseUri);

Builder b = target.path("somepath").request();

// I want to log the request here, before sending the request                   

Response response = b.put(Entity.json(jsonString));

//At this point request is sent and response is received.
```

Comment: How do you want the request to be printed?  Can you just lift the printing code from wherever it is and add it to your application, or even call it in place if possible?

Comment: I just want the string representation of the request. I checked the jersey source code and debugged a little bit, but I was not able to identify how Jersey prints to the console. Even if I could identify that part, I don't think I would be able to hook into the process.

Comment: You said you found code on the web that facilitates logging. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn The code is the one I added to the description. Registering a LoggingFeature facilitates logging to the logger file, but I could not find a way to get the string representation of the request before even making the request.